# Calculating a prediction score

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a prediction score script where users can pick a result.

I want to count the values of rows... For example, if in my DB contains 9 rows and 6 rows have the same value and other 3 different.. I want to get the value from 6 same rows and add them up together. Thanks.

Code:

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Score Predictions</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="id">
        <?php
            $query="SELECT * FROM test";
            $result=mysql_query($query);

            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){     
                $id = $row['id'];
                $home = $row['home'];
                $away = $row['away'];
            }
        ?>
        <?php
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])){   
                $x = $_POST["test"];
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (home, away, score) VALUES ('$home', '$away', '$x')"); 
             }
        ?>
        <?php echo $home," - ",$away; ?>
        <form method='post' action='http://albsocial.us/test/index.php'>
            <select name='test'> 
                <option value="" selected='selected'></option>
                <option VALUE='1'>1</option>
                <option VALUE='X'>X</option>
                <option VALUE='2'>2</option>   
            </select>       
            <INPUT TYPE='submit' name='submit' />   
        </form>

        <?php       
            $query="SELECT * FROM test";
            $result=mysql_query($query);

            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                $id = $row['id'];
                $score = $row['score'];

                if ($score = "1"){
                    echo "OK";
                }
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please see the [help about on topic subjects](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  This is not a site to write some code and ask for help finishing it.

Comment: @c_plus_plus_rookie I consider this is not a smart question, however I have given a 1+. In order your questio not to be closed. You are not asking for an issue on your code, you are looking for a solution, like "please do my homework" that is the reason on why people is making close your question, please fix your  post in order you get an answer, cause it looks like a valid question, but you do it on a wrong way

Comment: The fact that there is some code at all is worth a look. There's really not much more to do to answer the question. I'm mostly upset that I had an answer written up but was blocked from answering before it was closed.

Comment: IDK but i need help because when i try to validate the code in if($score = "1") its not giving me the rows where the value is only 1 ... so i clearly understand php and im not looking for you to do my homework..if this is not a help site than sorry for asking.

Comment: @JoeFrambach You may write your answer now ;-)

Comment: Given the issue and fix, perhaps worth reading up on [PHP comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few points to address:

*The DB Schema*

I'm assuming your table looks like this:

```
id INT,
home VARCHAR,
away VARCHAR,
score VARCHAR
```

where `score` can contain `1`, `2`, or `X`. It looks like you have rows of sporting event matches *home* vs *away*, where the user can submit their vote of who will win. If this isn't correct please update your question.

*if in my db are 9 rows and 6 rows have the same value and other 3 different.. i only want to get the value from 6 same rows and add them up together*

```
SELECT score, c FROM (
    SELECT score, count(score) as c FROM my_table GROUP BY count(score)
) as subselect
ORDER BY c DESC
LIMIT 1
```

That will get you the score with the most votes. I hope you can read it without much explanation.

*The php error*

```
if ($score = "1"){
```

is incorrect. To do a comparison you want:

```
if ($score == "1"){
```

*The other php error*

`$home` and `$away` in the `INSERT` will always be set to the values of the last row in your db table, because of how your while loop is set up. I'm not sure what you meant to do here, but this is worth pointing out.

From here, I have no idea what you actually intend to do with all of this code. This is just as far as I can tell from what you wrote.

Comment: THANKS A LOT BROTHER ... IT was the == instead of just = . I completely messed up there .. And thanks for understanding my question and helped to reopen it